# jquerymobile dialog not working, but popup is

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a javascript object where I set

```
this.popupWin = $('<div data-role="popup" id="dialog-1">Hello</div>').appendTo(this.container);

this.popupLink = $('<a  data-rel="popup" href="#dialog-1>mylink</a>').appendTo(this.container);
```

which seems to work fine.

However, if I set `data-role` and `data-rel` to `dialog` a dialog does not appear.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you insert it into `data-role=page` div? if yes, it should be added out of `page` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the `dialog` div outside `data-role=page` div.